# no debug.keystore in .android folder

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-7, sdk, sample

I am desperately trying to write a simple app but I'm encountering problems with every step so I thought I'd try playing with one of the sample apps provided with the SDK - what could go wrong - right?

When following the instructions to copy the sample and edit it, I get "Failed to load properties file for project xxx" no matter which project i try.
Following the advice on this forum, I went looking for my debug.keystore so I could delet/recreate it only to find it missing

Help!!

Oh Yeah - Windoze 7, Eclipse 4.2.0, Android SDK 20.0.3

Comment: debug keystore is an automaticaly created file how come it goes missing It should be in ur users -> <username> ->.android file try restarting eclipse and runing an available prog it should be created automaticaly

Comment: If the problem with missing of .apk file, then create your own .apk file and change the path in eclipse: Preferences -> Android -> build -> browse the path (Which is generated newly).

Answer (score 1):

The debug.keystore file is created by the ADT Plugin in eclipse. Make sure you have installed the ADT plugin compatible to your eclipse version.

As your using eclipse juno. This is the url you will have to use install the plugin

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/

On the steps to install the plugin goto

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

**NOTE: the above link still shows the old url for eclipse. You need to use 
the url given above for eclipse 4.2 juno.**

Answer (score 0):

Had same error win 7 64bit eclipse   3.7 indigo and 4.2.1 juno
deleted debug keystore. did clean and buile worked perfect build no errors. A restart of eclipse was not necessary